# Clarifying terminology - What does "hydrating" a JPA or Hibernate entity mean when fetching the entity from the DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, lazy-loading

In the context of ORM / Lazy loading of entities, my understanding of the term "Hydration" is as follows:

"Hydrating" describes the process of populating some or all of the previously unpopulated attributes of an entity fetched using lazy loading.

Eg:  class `Author` is loaded from the database:

```
@Entity
class Author
{
     @Id
     long id;
     List<Book> books;
}
```

Initially, the `books` collection is not populated.

It is my understanding that the process of loading the `books` collection from the database is referred to as "Hydrating" the collection.

Is this definition correct, and is the term common place?  Is there another more common term I should be using for this process?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Yes the definition is correct, the term ***hydration*** is a conceptual  metaphor used to describe setting the member properties of an object/model, (post-instantiation/creation) with the values from its associated database record.

Its common nomenclature for ORM/Persistence libraries. BizTalk, JPA, Hibernate and Doctrine all use the concept to various degrees, for instance, BizTalk also explicitly defines ***dehydrated*** to mean the state where an object/model has been instantiated (created) but not yet ***hydrated*** (a required life-cycle state to lazy load and or model self referencing relations)

Some are averse to the terms adoption, arguing that it is redundant, a marketing tool, or disliking terminology overhauls, sighting the adequacy of ***populated***, ***empty*** and ***clear*** to describe the life-cycle.

Others find the metaphor useful to solve confusion where ***populated*** is commonly used to describe a collection's state (as opposed to an object/model) as well.

The term has been in use for years now, more recently being borrowed by JavaScript Frameworks (e.g. React) to describe the distinct but similar concept of integrating server rendered components into client side object models.

Its safe to say, they are here to stay.

Comment: Of course it is, however, it was first, it's simple and as such it's far less convoluted. You may have also realised at this point that pretty much everything on the software layer, even a bit value being "true/false" or "1/0" is metaphorical... Should we start calling 'true' something else now? How about 'almost certainly' in respect to Heisenberg?

Comment: I think "hydrate" is a far better metaphor than "populate". Populate brings to mind a group of colonizers moving to a foreign or virgin territory and "populating" it. There is an empty space and you fill it with something unrelated (but presumably belongs there). Where when hydrating something, say a dried fig, the essence of the substance is there but it lacks fullness. That's exactly what happens when you "hydrate" an object. Far from being "marketing fluff", hydrate is an excellent metaphor.

Comment: @KyleMathews Well, it's three years on since I posted my answer, I didn't make explicitly clear that "Populated" was the pre-existing term for the same activity, at this point "Hydrated" is still a marginal term, and is only used in certain language/product cultures, while "Populated" remains as the generic and more broadly used term.  By all means go ahead and use "Hydrate" if it pleases you, personally I find it pretentious and affected.

Comment: If you use "hydrate" around people who don't understand that word, you're going to have to explain it. Why not just use a word that's already going to be understandable by your audience, even if it's not the most precise word possible?

Comment: While I agree that the choice of the term 'hydration' might be disputable (it does sound a bit too obscure), especially since it doesn't immediately imply loading of the data from a data store into memory, I think it is a distinct process from 'population', which normally refers to filling abstract data types such as arrays, lists, trees and tables with elements, irrespective of whether it is in memory or in a persistent storage. We populate an array with all the users, we populate a table with all the transaction records. We hydrate a new product instance with its data.

Comment: How about _inflate_ and _deflate_ in that context? _[yes, I am aware it's an old question and an old discussion]_

Comment: As it happens deflate / inflate is old compression terminology used by [lha/lzh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LHA_(file_format))

Comment: The fact that nobody knows what hydrate is supposed to mean without looking it up shows that it is a stupid buzz word that is unfortunately now entrenched in many ORM frameworks.

Comment: I could've said that as my answer, but it's a little blunt.  Can't say I disagree though.

Comment: I don't remember ever encountering this term "hydrate" before today. For ever me and my colleagues have been using other more common terms to mean we are filling an object with stuff -- like "fill".

Comment: @PedroLamarão - I was talking about this with my wife today, and she said "fill(ing) up" or "fill(ing) out" is the way people talked about this activity before the daft _attempted-verb-creation_.  It's fun to think of filling out a form as "hydrating a form", insisting it's the "new" way we say that...  and then trying really hard not to cringe.

Answer (score 21):

### Entity loaded state

When you are fetching an entity, Hibernate will try to load it either from the second-level cache or the database.

[image: Entity loaded state]

If the entity is not stored in the second-level cache, then a query is executed and the JDBC `ResultSet` is transformed into an `Object[]` that contains the loading-time entity property values.

The second-level cache stores this `Object[]` when caching an entity. So, when loading an entity either from the DB or the second-level cache, you will get the `Object[]` entity property value array.

The process of transforming the `Object[]` loaded state into a Java entity object is called *hydration*, and it looks as follows:

```
final Object[] values = persister.hydrate(
    rs, id, object,
    rootPersister, cols, eagerPropertyFetch, session
);
```

The loaded state is saved in the currently running Persistence Context as an [EntityEntry](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/spi/EntityEntry.html) object, and it will be used later for the default dirty checking mechanism, which compares the current entity data against the loading-time snapshot.

The loaded state is also used as the cache entry value for the second-level entity cache.

The inverse operation of transforming the entity to an `Object[]` that's used when binding SQL parameter values for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements is called [*dehydration*](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/persister/entity/AbstractEntityPersister.html#dehydrate-java.io.Serializable-java.lang.Object:A-boolean:A-boolean:A:A-int-java.sql.PreparedStatement-org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor-boolean-).

Answer (score 4):

"Hydration" is a loose term. In our company we use "rehydration" as the term to load all the object properties of an entire object graph. [Here is a post](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-23439.html) that talks about various levels of hydration (again this is a general usage though they are using in the context of Hibernate).

Comment: That link no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

I think the term 'hydrate(s)' in the context of ORM simply means the framework gives you objects.  So the objects are 'hydrated' by the ORM after the data is pulled from the store.  The term can be applied anytime an ORM framework gives you an object/graph that is represented in the store.

Answer (score 0):

the term hydration is extensively used in the guts of the hibernate library to refer to the process of setting the fields of a recently loaded object, and is indeed related to the object graph populaton.
but it's different than the concept of lazy loading, that is, giving the user a half-filled object and letting the rest be loaded on demand.
the hydration is always performed, lazily or eagerly and it's hibernate stuff.
lazy loading is just for convenience

replace hibernate with the name of your orm of choice

Answer (score -1):

*Hydration* is a general ORM domain term meaning a **method** by which the query result is returned. It's not a process, not a verb, not an action or event that occurs but a noun. Therefore *to hydrate* simply means *to use a hydration method*. Hydration method creates a structure that represents data. There's a popular misconception, though, that every hydration not only instantiates an object but also populates it before returning its reference. That's not a rule. While a specific hydration can also populate an object, not all hydrations do that. Different hydrations return different structures:

- singular scalar
- array of scalars
- array of arrays
- array of objects
- object collecting scalars
- object collecting arrays
- object collecting other objects
- ...more

It's an ORM implementation detail. Some ORMs provide multiple hydrations and you can choose one by passing an argument to query builder, some don't give you that control and replace it by convention trying to be smart about it (which is the source of the hydration/population misconception mentioned above). More advanced ones allow you to write your own hydrators for custom objects that can map field types. The term itself is closely related to deserialization (which is more general and doesn't necessarily involve a database or an ORM).