# Why is the second parameter to JSON.parse called “reviver”?

Tags: javascript, json, terminology

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> - **`reviver`** (Optional)
>
>   If a function, prescribes how the value originally produced by parsing is transformed, before being returned.

Its name strikes me as odd. Maybe I’m missing a metaphor here — why would this be called “reviving” an object? Is there any history to such a transformer function being called a “reviver”? Googling `reviver +javascript` shows that `JSON.parse` is basically the only place where this term is used.

Comment: Maybe because it's function used to `revive` JSON from string? Still it's better naming than `parameter` or `asdlkasflks`...

Answer (score 5):

The idea is that native Javascript objects, like a `Number(42)`, are your "live" objects. When you serialise those into a JSON representation, they're "dried up", or "dumbed down", or whatever you want to call it. To get your fresh live Javascript objects back, you need to "revive" them from their simple text representation.

This becomes more apparent if you use more complex objects:

```
function Foo(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}

Foo.prototype.baz = function () {
    alert(this.bar);
};

var f = Foo(42);
f.baz();
f = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(f));
f.baz();  // Nope
```

To get the original object back which has a `baz` method, you need to do a little more than just `parse` it. That's the "reviving" part.

Comment: I’ve considered roughly this interpretation, and it makes the most sense to me! I’ll wait for some sort of official citation to roll in, but your example helped solidify my hunch :)

Comment: Other languages have similar analogies. See "hydrate" in the Java world: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991135/what-does-it-mean-to-hydrate-an-object

Answer (score 1):

The `parse` function is used to create an object from data that has been serialized into a string. By default, all it can do is reconstitute the data into plain objects with a bunch of properties.

Sometimes, you may want to "bring these values back to life" (i.e. *revive* them) into full-fledged objects with methods, behaviors, etc., or even objects that have a particular type, instead of just the lifeless containers of values that `JSON.parse()` produces by default.

I would say that's why it's called a `reviver`.