# What does dehydration mean in the context of data loading?

Tags: hydration

There are a few threads which discuss the meaning of data hydration.

But I can't find any definitions of data dehydration.

I can see three possible meanings

> 1) Extracting the current state of an object
>
> 2) Clearing the state of an object
>
> 3) Both 1) and 2)

**EDIT**

**This is not a duplicate** of other threads where the meaning of *hydration* is discussed. This question is about *dehydration*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean to hydrate an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991135/what-does-it-mean-to-hydrate-an-object)

Comment: @Enigmativity This is NOT a duplicate. The linked thread only references hydration. Not dehydration.

Comment: I cannot see any detail in your question that helps distinguish this question. Please read [ask]. If I were to edit this question to remove unnecessary text I would delete everything in the content. Please provide a suitable description of what you are asking.

Comment: What about the question in the subject line is unclear to you? I cannot imagine a more clearly stated question.

Comment: The title is all that I had to go on, which is why I marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

**De**hydration is simply the opposite of hydration. In context of data loading, given you have an API that reads data from an ORM. The process to transform the ORM object tree into a JSON with primitive types in it, is dehydration. The extraction of data from the hydrated objects.

As you already mentioned:

> Extracting the current state of an object

Answer (score -3):

Data dehydration usually refers to the process of storing db data off in a compressed file. The data is then removed from the db (and as such is inaccessible)

The process of rehydration is loading the stored data into the original or ancillary table so that it can be worked with.