# Why my programme return NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I am working on a spring's stock management application.
I have a function that create an invoice (facture), it create the invoice with the id of the customer (client), and in it I have an other function that create the invoice details.
this is my entities:

the invoice entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Facture implements Serializable {
    
    public Facture(float d, float e, Date date, boolean b, Set<DetailFacture> detailFactures2, Client c1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idFacture")
    private Long idFacture;
    @Column(name="montantRemise")
    private  float  montantRemise;
    @Column(name="montantFacture")
    private  float  montantFacture;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="dateFacture")
    private Date dateFacture;
    @Column(name="active")
    private boolean active;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="facture")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<DetailFacture> detailFactures;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Client client;
    
}
```

the invoice details entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class DetailFacture implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idDetailFacture")
    private Long idDetailFacture;
    @Column(name="qte")
    private  float  qte;
    @Column(name="prixTotal")
    private  float  prixTotal;
    @Column(name="pourcentageRemise")
    private int pourcentageRemise;
    @Column(name="montantRemise")
    private int montantRemise;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Produit produit;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Facture facture;

    
}
```

the customer entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Client implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idClient")
    private Long idClient;
    @Column(name="nom")
    private String nom;
    @Column(name="prenom")
    private String prenom;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="dateNaissance")
    private Date dateNaissance;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="categorieClient")
    private CategorieClient categorieClient;
    @Column(name="profession")
    private Profession profession;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client")
    private List<Facture> factures;

    
}
```

this is my function in the invoice service that create an invoice with the customer id:

```
@Override
    @Transactional
    public Facture addFactureClient(Facture f, Long idClient) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Client client = clientRepository.findById(idClient).orElse(null);
        f.setClient(client);
        f.setDateFacture(new Date());
        f.setActive(true);
        Set<DetailFacture> detailfactures = f.getDetailFactures();
        Facture facture = addDetailFacture(f, detailfactures);
        return factureRepository.save(facture);
    }
```

and this is the function that create the invoice details:

```
private Facture addDetailFacture(Facture f, Set<DetailFacture> detailfactures){
        float montantFacture = 0;
        float montantRemise = 0;
        System.out.println(detailfactures);
        for (DetailFacture detail : detailfactures){
            Produit produit = produitRepository.findById(detail.getProduit().getIdProduit()).orElse(null);
            float prixTotalDetail = detail.getQte() * produit.getPrixUnitaire();
            float montantRemiseDetail = (prixTotalDetail * detail.getPourcentageRemise())/100;
            float prixTotalDetailRemise = prixTotalDetail - montantRemiseDetail;
            detail.setMontantRemise((int)montantRemiseDetail);
            detail.setPrixTotal(prixTotalDetailRemise);
            montantFacture = montantFacture + prixTotalDetailRemise;
            montantRemise = montantRemise + montantRemiseDetail;
            detail.setProduit(produit);
            detail.setFacture(f);
            detailFactureRepository.save(detail);
        }
        f.setMontantFacture(montantFacture);
        f.setMontantRemise(montantRemise);
        return f;
    }
```

this is the function in my controller:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Ajouter facture avec client")
    @PostMapping("/add-facture/{idClient}")
    @ResponseBody
    Facture addFacture(@RequestBody Facture f, @PathVariable("idClient") long idClient) {
        return factureService.addFactureClient(f, idClient);
    }
```

this is how I am testing with postman:
[image]

the problem is when I create a new invoice it returns a NullPointerException in this line :

```
Facture facture = addDetailFacture(f, detailfactures);
```

why detailfactures returns null?

Comment: That line cannot cause a null pointer exception. A line inside the method `addDetailFacture` could, but not this call itself. Use a debugger and step through your code to check which variable is null.

Comment: Please add always the complete stacktrace. Without it is impossible to help

Comment: if guess `detailfactures` is null that's why `for (DetailFacture detail : detailfactures){` throws a `NullPointerException`

Comment: *why detailfactures returns null?* because it is not in your rquest structure

Comment: I change the request in postman like this:
    {
        "detailFactures":{
            "qte": 3.0,
            "pourcentageRemise": 20,
            "produit":{
                "idProduit":1
            }
        }
    }
but its the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is the method you have a problem with

```
private Facture addDetailFacture(Facture f, Set<DetailFacture> detailfactures){
        float montantFacture = 0;
        float montantRemise = 0;
        System.out.println(detailfactures);
        for (DetailFacture detail : detailfactures){
            Produit produit = produitRepository.findById(detail.getProduit().getIdProduit()).orElse(null);
            float prixTotalDetail = detail.getQte() * produit.getPrixUnitaire();
            float montantRemiseDetail = (prixTotalDetail * detail.getPourcentageRemise())/100;
            float prixTotalDetailRemise = prixTotalDetail - montantRemiseDetail;
            detail.setMontantRemise((int)montantRemiseDetail);
            detail.setPrixTotal(prixTotalDetailRemise);
            montantFacture = montantFacture + prixTotalDetailRemise;
            montantRemise = montantRemise + montantRemiseDetail;
            detail.setProduit(produit);
            detail.setFacture(f);
            detailFactureRepository.save(detail);
        }
        f.setMontantFacture(montantFacture);
        f.setMontantRemise(montantRemise);
        return f;
    }
```

NPE (`NullPointerException`) happens when your code tries to refer a data member or call a method of an object that is `null`.

What could be `null` in your case:

- `detailfactures`
- `produitRepository`
- `detail`
- `detail.getProduit()`
- `produitRepository.findById(detail.getProduit().getIdProduit())`
- `detail`
- `produit`
- `detail.getPourcentageRemise()`
- `f`

In order to find out what is `null` from these candidates, you will need to debug your application or look at the detailed error message to find out which line threw the `null`. Once that is found, you will know what is `null` and you will have the following options:

- you can find out why it is `null` in the first place and fix the code chunk which originated the problem
- you can `try`-`catch` and handle the `null` case with some special error-handling code

Comment: detailfactures is the one that returns null but I can't figure out why?

Comment: @KhalilFathalli your `Set<DetailFacture> detailfactures = f.getDetailFactures();` line is the culprit then. It is probably the case that you have a foreign key with `null` as value in your database.

Comment: you are right f.getDetailFactures() returns null but in my database I don't have a a foreign key with null

Comment: @KhalilFathalli maybe your Facture is not hydrated.

Comment: and how can I fix that_

Comment: @KhalilFathalli this may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929243/clarifying-terminology-what-does-hydrating-a-jpa-or-hibernate-entity-mean-wh